Vite.js Failed to resolve module specifier "external-library". Relative references must start with either "/", "./" or "../"
I have this issue when I build my application
localhost/:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lib-model". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
To reproduice
I create vue project
npm create vue

My tree
zproject
|--lib (external library)
|  |--index.ts
|  |--person.model.ts
|--vue-project (vuejs project)
|  |--vite.config.ts
|  |--package.json

package.json (vuejs)
{
  "name": "vue-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "run-p type-check \"build-only {@}\" --",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "type-check": "vue-tsc --build --force"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lib-model": "file:../lib/model",
    "vue": "^3.4.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node20": "^20.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.5",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.5.1",
    "npm-run-all2": "^6.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.0",
    "vite": "^5.3.1",
    "vue-tsc": "^2.0.21"
  }
  ,"optionalDependencies": {
    "@rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu": "4.9.5",
    "@rollup/rollup-win32-x64-gnu": "4.13.1-1",
    "@rollup/rollup-win32-x64-msvc": "4.19.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "11.1.6"
  }
}


vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
  , build:{
    rollupOptions:{
      external:['lib-model'],// fix error during build
    }
    ,commonjsOptions:{
      include:["lib-model"], // fix error during dev
    }
  
  }
  , optimizeDeps:{
    include:["lib-model"] // fix error during dev
  }
  , 
})

App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import {Person} from 'lib-model'

const user = new Person();

</script>

<template>
  <header>
    Hello : {{ user }}
    
  </header>

</template>

my lib
/zproject/lib/model/person.model.ts
export class Person {
  firstname:string = ""
  lastname:string= "";
}

When I run npm run dev, that works ! (but I have need to add options in vite.config.js rollupOptions,commonjsOptions,optimizeDeps)

but when I run npm run build
rm -fr ./node_modules/.vite/;
npm run build;
> vue-project@0.0.0 build
> run-p type-check "build-only {@}" --


> vue-project@0.0.0 type-check
> vue-tsc --build --force


> vue-project@0.0.0 build-only
> vite build

vite v5.4.10 building for production...
✓ 25 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                  0.43 kB │ gzip:  0.29 kB
dist/assets/index-D27_py02.css   3.71 kB │ gzip:  1.19 kB
dist/assets/index-B4PfWo-J.js   58.78 kB │ gzip: 23.62 kB
✓ built in 7.09s

Then I launch my browser
(For your information, I have nginx configured)

For your information, this structure works before I use vite.
I think the issue is on the vite.config.ts setting up but I don't found.
I need to keep my module as external module.
I don't want to use git
Thanks for your help !

"I need to keep my module as external module" - how exactly do you expect this to work? External modules are needed when a bundle is imported in other bundles, in this case they are responsible for bundling external dep themselves. In your case the import happens in a browser where  "lib-model" doesn't exist. Currently it looks like you misinterpreted the term "external module". You probably need "alias", based on the context

@EstusFlask.  That works before! Since I use vite I have this issue. I'm pretty sure the issue is in config.
I think I need to prebuild this module before.

Can you clarify what you mean? It worked before you used vite? It's unclear then what you compare to what. Did you try to not mention 'lib-model' in vite config? What does happen then?

when I used vue-cli-service build
Since vite.  It doesn't work
I always have an external module.
I vite.config.js , I see https://vite.dev/config/build-options.html#build-modulepreload
But it doesn't work

Vue cli is different and doesn't have "external" option, and even if it had, it would mean a different thing. As I said, these options that mention  'lib-model' (optimizeDeps, external) are potentially not needed. If "file:" protocol causes it to be installed by npm to node_modules/lib-model , it shouldn't differ from other dependencies, it can be bundled. If there's a problem without these options, please, explain it in details and provide a way to reproduce, so it could be debugged

@EstusFlask I found it !
I was pretty sure that is possible.
But, I don't really explain that because,
I have use it a few year ago
but after the new version of vuejs it doen't work, and now that works
in App.vue
//import {Person} from 'lib-model' // error in build
import {Person} from 'lib-model/person.model' // fix build

It wasn't shown what ./lib-model looks like, so nothing could be suggested. In order for lib-model import to work as is, you need package.json inside of it that maps person.model.ts with module/main/export entries, e.g. https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/master/packages/primevue/src/panel/package.json

I found the solution
in my App.vue

//import {Person} from 'lib-model' // error in build
import {Person} from 'lib-model/index' // fix build

That means, need to seek the class that I want to use directly, instead of use my index.js
// index.js
export {Person} from "./person.model"

And After that I run
npm run build

And That work !

The use of index.js would require to use 'lib-model/index' import instead of 'lib-model' . As said above, in order for 'lib-model' to work consistently, lib-model/ needs to contain package.json that has "main", etc entry that maps entry point to index.js

You right ! I use 'lib-model/index'
And that works as well  ! Thx
Like I said, my tree at above shows I have an index.ts but that didn't work
